# How to configure foreach loop properly to avoid index out of range error?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, foreach

I have one object :

```
 public List<double> obj { get; set; }

public class Employee
{
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public int Skillssetpoints { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

Records are like this:

```
EmployeeId   SkillssetPoints   Date
 1              5             4/5/2016 16:12:12
 2              12             3/5/2016 17:12:12
 3              4              8/5/2016 8:12:12
 4              20             1/5/2016 2:12:12
```

This obj will contaisn value like this:

```
"obj":[10,20]
```

Now what i want to do is i will get all employee data and for each employee data i will perform multiplication
like this:

```
1st records:obj[0] * Skillssetpoints  (10*5=50)
2nd records:obj[0] * Skillssetpoints  (20*12=240)
```

This is my loop:

```
var employeeList=context.Employee.ToList();

  foreach (var item in employeeList.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }))
  {
          var employee = new Employee();
          employee.Skillssetpoints=obj[item.index] * item.Skillssetpoints;
          //Save records in database
  }
```

But here problem is i am getting 4 records for employee and my obj contains 2 values so getting below error:

**Error:Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.**

**Note**:I also want to consider the case when my employee records would be less than no of items in the list object.

How to configure this loop properly properly??

Comment: Are you sure you have equal number of records to `emplyeeList`?

Comment: @HariPrasad:Number of employee records and data in list object can be different like sometimes employee records can be greater than data in list object and sometimes employee records can be less than data in list object

Comment: How do you map employee to obj in that case? Do you want to update only employee having valid `value` and ignore if `value` are not available (in `obj`)?

Comment: @Learning You have shown for the 1st & 2nd records, now how the multiplication should be for the 3rd and 4th records in the above example?

Comment: @har07 that's what I want OP to confirm, whether to ignore them or get  value having any condition?

Comment: @HariPrasad:Yes i only want to insert data in to employee table as far as values in List obj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to process only the first `n` items according to the number of items in `obj` :

```
foreach (employeeList.Take(obj.Count).Select((value, index) => new { value, index }))
{
    .....
}
```

This should also work for the case when the number of items in `obj` are more then there are in `employeeList`. In this case, only as much data as the `employeeList` has will be processed.

Comment: but still this will insert data in to my tables when my data in list obj are less than employee records and your solution is giving wrong results

Comment: you are really genius man.Can you explain a little bit what you have done??

Comment: @Learning thanks, I just borrowed the power of LINQ. Not sure what else to explain, `Take()` method is used to return only the first `n` items in a collection, that's it. Check the linked documentation above. Let me know which particular part you need more explanation if this isn't clear

Comment: Actually i was too looking for such answer otherwise this could be done with some logic but i too wanted to use the power of linq and which you have done superbly

Answer (score 1):

Calculate skill points only if you have valid `Value` in `obj`.

```
foreach (var item in employeeList.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }))
{
      var employee = new Employee();
      if(item.index >= 0) // Calculate Skill points only when value is avialable.
         employee.Skillssetpoints=obj[item.index] * item.Skillssetpoints;
      //Save records in database
}
```

In case if you want to ignore inserting empty records, you can call `break` inside loop.

```
foreach (var item in employeeList.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }))
{
      var employee = new Employee();
      if(item.index < 0) break;

      employee.Skillssetpoints=obj[item.index] * item.Skillssetpoints;
      //Save records in database
}
```